# Synchronise two different instances of AzMan

Tags: import, export, azman

I'm wondering does any one know how to sync data between two instances of AzMan?

I've created a big list of tasks and operations in the test instance of AzMan and I need to move it to another server for UAT.

I've googled around and the closest solution I found was a [bulk import/export tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/ashishme/archive/2006/12/01/azman-store-import-export.aspx), but there's no document on how to run it :(

Answer (score 0):

What about [this one](http://www.leastprivilege.com/SourceCodeForAzManBulkImporter.aspx)? It has source code and brief instructions.